# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error raised when trying to send message through Python to telegram bot

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to send message through python request to telegram bot. but I kept getting 400 Client Error. Here is the code:

```
import requests
def send(text):
    token = 'your_token_goes_here'
    params = {'chat_id': xxx, 'text': text, 'parse_mode': 'HTML'}
    resp = requests.post('https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/sendMessage'.format(token), params)
    resp.raise_for_status()
send('hello')
```

Here is the error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here is what i see when i open the URL:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}
```

1. I tried this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009755/python-get-raises-httperror-400-client-error-but-after-manually-accessing-url). I used the latest agent user string

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36
```

from [here](https://www.useragentstring.com/Chrome104.0.5112.79_id_19986.php).
It didn't work. same error

2. I tried to check whether it's requests.post has a problem. Used requests.post to retrieve data from other API. it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I used the wrong chat_id.

Comment: Apparently you got a 400, which normally represents malformed syntax and not a not found as it should be the case for a non-existent ID. I would have expected a 404 in this case. Was the wrong `chat_id` in the wrong format?

Comment: @JoãoEsperancinha Nah, not the wrong format. I used the bot's chat id where I should've used my own chat id